# .htaccess using public folder and SEO friendly URL

Tags: url-routing, .htaccess

.htaccess is not my strong suit. Is there any there can optimize this code?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)
RewriteRule (.*) /public/$1

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]


ErrorDocument 500 "Sorry, our script crashed. Oh dear"
ErrorDocument 500 /cgi-bin/crash-recover
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 401 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html
```

don't know if it necessary but here are an example of the folder system

- app
- public

  - index.php
  - contact.php
  - forum

    - last_news.php
    - users

      - user.php
    - ask.php
- .htaccess

Answer (score 2):

1. Redundant `RewriteEngine` declarations
2. Unused match group in `(public)`
3. Escaping (using `\`) is not needed in the new URLs
4. A personal touch, but I prefer to keep the core directives at the top, and put module specific directives inside `<IfModule>` body, so that I won't receive errors if the modules are disabled.
5. Multiple declarations for `ErrorDocument 500`

---

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

ErrorDocument 401 /subscription/how_to_subscribe.html# Turn mod_rewrite on
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/not_found.html
ErrorDocument 500 http://error.example.com/server_error.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(public)
    RewriteRule ^ /%1%{REQUEST_URI}

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```